# How to use a component in vue without re-render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rerender

I have a canvas element into a component, I need make a lot of calculus to draw something, but every time I call a method the component is re-rendering, so this make the application very slow.

```
<canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" @input="draw()" />
```

Any ideas how call a method without execute a re-render function ?

Thanks...

Comment: Calling a method should not be causing the re-render unless you are changing the component's state in the method.

Comment: You're right, I had a mistake in my code...